# Dynamic Datasource Connection in Spring

Tags: java, database, spring

When my application starts it creates connection with one database. During runtime I fetched other databases names in same database server. How can I create connection for other databases too at runtime? Currently I am passing dbNameto method like:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public DataSource getDataSource(String dbName) {

    String dbUrl = DATABASE_JDBC_URL + dbName;

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
    dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    return dataSource;
}
```

When I pass parameter **dbName** in above @Bean `getDataSource(String dbName)` method I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Singleton scope bean

```
@Bean
public DBName getDBName(){
    return new DBName();
 }
```

and pass this bean by setting database name to datasource bean each time when you want new database connection

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public DataSource getDataSource(DBName dbNameObj) {
...

}
```

DBName class can be written as

```
public class DBName {

    private String dbName;

    public String getDbName() {
        return dbName;
    }

    public void setDbName(String dbName) {
        this.dbName = dbName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper around Datasource, something like :

```
@Component
public class DataSourceManager implements DataSource{

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // init the datasource
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource(String dbName) {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void switchDataSource(String name) {
        // re init the datasource
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    .... wrap all the other DataSource methods

}
```